# Checking for empty selection in php does not give the right result

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have sell.php and a sell_form.php files. They are working fine in selling but I want to try and give an error message to the user if they select an empty value for the stock symbol. I have implemented

```
'if(["blank"]){
        apologize("You must select a stock symbol");
    }'
```

I get the error message with this if statement but I am not able to sell the selected stock either. I do not know where I am making a mistake. I also tried using this if statement

```
'if([empty($_POST["symbol"])){
        apologize("You must select a stock symbol");
    }'
```

and this redirects me to the home page with no errors. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code for my two files.
sell.php

```
//configuration
require("../includes/config.php");

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{

    if(empty($_POST["symbol"])){

        apologize("You must select a stock symbol");

    }  

    // lookup stock
    $stock = lookup($_POST["symbol"]);

    // lookup user's shares of stock being sold
    $shares = query("SELECT shares FROM shares WHERE id = ? AND symbol = ?",  $_SESSION["id"], $_POST["symbol"]);

    // calculate total sale value (stock's price * shares)
    $value = $stock["price"] * $shares[0]["shares"];

    $date = date("Y-m-d, H:i:s");

    // add the sale value to cash
    query("UPDATE users SET cash = cash + ? WHERE id = ?", $value, $_SESSION["id"]);

    // delete the stock from their portfolio 
    query("DELETE FROM shares WHERE id = ? AND symbol = ?", $_SESSION["id"], $_POST["symbol"]);  

    query("INSERT INTO history (id, symbol, soldOrBought, numberOfSharesBoughtOrSold, price, dateAndTime)
          VALUES (?, ?, 'Sold', ?, ?, ?)", $_SESSION["id"], strtoupper($_POST["symbol"]), $shares[0]["shares"], $stock["price"], $date );



redirect("/");
}
else
{

$rows = query("SELECT * FROM shares WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);

    //create array to store the shares
    $shares = [];

    //for each of the user info

    foreach($rows as $row){

        //lookup stock info
        $stock = lookup($row["symbol"]);
        if($stock !== false){

            $shares[] = [
                "name" => $stock["name"],
                "price" => $stock["price"],
                "shares" => $row["shares"],
                "symbol" => $row["symbol"],
                "total" => $row["shares"]*$stock["price"]
            ];

        }
    }

// render portfolio
render("sell_form.php", ["shares" => $shares, "title" => "Sell"] );
}

?>
```

sell_form.php

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" >

<li >
    <a href="index.php">Portfolio</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="quote.php">Quote</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="buy.php">Buy</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="sell.php">Sell</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="history.php">History</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="deposit.php">Deposit Funds</a>
</li>    

</ul>
<form action="sell.php" method="post">
<fieldset>     
    <div class="control-group">

        <select name="symbol">
        <option value="blank"></option>

        <?php foreach ($shares as $symbol):?>
        <option value="<?= $symbol["symbol"]?>"><?= $symbol["symbol"]?></option>
         <? endforeach ?>
        </select>     

    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Sell all shares</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
<div>
or <a href="logout.php">log out</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selectlist can either contain a "blank" option, with the value "blank", so checking for empty wont work on a regular post of the form.

Your check should be:

```
if(empty($_POST["symbol"]) || $_POST["symbol"]=="blank") {

    apologize("You must select a stock symbol");

}
```

Now it will show this message when the value is completely missing or when the value is "blank". Another option would be to alter the select list to have the first option like

```
<select name="symbol">
<option value=""></option>
```

Then all you need is a check for `if (empty($_POST["symbol"])) { }`

Comment: Quick question if you do not mind. Why does it work with value="" but not with value="blank" ?

Comment: The value in the `option` tag is what is sent to the server. So if you have the value as "blank" you are sending a string that contains that word. PHP does not know english to understand that you mean no value. In dutch for example blank means caucasian, so then it could be an actual value you select. If you have the option value as "" you are seding an empty string to the server and that is considered empty. Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php to see what empty realy does.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, the function apologize() is printing the input text, then you have to terminate the execution after called that function. So that you can get error message. Just try as follows,

```
if(empty($_POST["symbol"])){
apologize("You must select a stock symbol");
die();
}
```

Edit: For more understanding, Post apologize() definition as well.